# Python sys.exit return code

Tags: python

I try to call another python script in a python script, and get the return code as follows:

```
print os.system("python -c 'import sys; sys.exit(0)'")
print os.system("python -c 'import sys; sys.exit(1)'")
```

I get return code 0 and 256. Why it returns 256, when I do sys.exit with value 1?

Answer (score 10):

Quoting the [`os.system()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system)

> On Unix, the return value is the exit status of the process **encoded in the format specified for `wait()`**. Note that POSIX does not specify the meaning of the return value of the C `system()` function, so **the return value of the Python function is system-dependent.**

Emphasis mine. The return value is system dependent, and returns an *encoded* format.

The [`os.wait()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.wait) says:

> Wait for completion of a child process, and return a tuple containing its pid and exit status indication: a 16-bit number, whose low byte is the signal number that killed the process, and whose high byte is the exit status (if the signal number is zero); the high bit of the low byte is set if a core file was produced.

This is *not* the exit status you are looking at, but an exit status *indication*, which is based of the return value of the C `system()` call, whose return value is system-dependent.

Here, your exit status of `1` is packed into the high byte of a 16-bit value:

```
>>> 1 << 8
256
```

You could extract the exit code and signal with:

```
exit_code, signal, core = status_ind >> 8, status_ind & 0x7f, bool(status_ind & 0x80)
```

but keep the *system-dependent* caveat in mind.

Use the [`subprocess` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) if you want to retrieve the exit code more reliably and easily.

Comment: Thank you for your information. I used _subprocess.call_ instead of _os.sytem_, and got the actual exist code.